# What changes my UTF-8 string to ASCII?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$string = $this->getTextFromHTML($html);

echo mb_detect_encoding($string, 'ASCII,UTF-8,ISO-8859-1');

$stringArray = mb_split('\W+', $string);
$cleaned = array();
foreach($stringArray as $v) {
    $string = trim($v);
    if(!empty($string))
        array_push($cleaned, $string);
}

echo mb_detect_encoding($stringArray[752], 'ASCII,UTF-8,ISO-8859-1');
```

The above returns:

```
// UTF-8
// ASCII
```

What part of my code is turning my string into `ASCII`? Or am I detecting the encoding incorrectly?

Comment: Try `true` for strict.  _strict specifies whether to use the strict encoding detection or not. Default is FALSE._

Comment: I set strict to `true` to both calls to mb_detect_encoding and nothing changed.

Comment: If your text only uses characters in the range `\x00` to `\x7f` then, both encodings are *exactly the same*. You can't detect one over the other.

Comment: The element `$stringArray[752]` contains a string. I just picked a random string to detect it's encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings have no actual associated encoding, they're merely byte arrays. `mb_detect_encoding` doesn't tell you what encoding the string has, it merely tries to ***detect*** it. That means it takes a few guesses (your second argument) and tells you the first that is valid.

Your original string probably contains some non-ASCII characters, so ASCII isn't a valid encoding for it, but UTF-8 is. When you're later testing a substring of the original, that substring probably contains only characters which are valid in ASCII, and since ASCII is the first encoding that's tested, that's the guessed result. Any ASCII string is also valid UTF-8, so there's no actual problem or "conversion" which happened.

Comment: Ah I see! This makes sense now. I'll have to look into converting to UTF8 then. Painful.

Comment: You don't need to convert anything. It's still ***also valid UTF-8*** at the same time as being valid ASCII! The only issue is that *guessing an encoding is fundamentally impossible.* Just do `mb_check_encoding($str, 'UTF-8')` instead; if that's `true`, your string is UTF-8.

Comment: I fear that I might have other character encodings in the rest of my string. As the string has been stitched together from many places.

Comment: If your original `mb_detect_encoding` call told you it's UTF-8, then everything in the string is UTF-8 (with very very very high likelihood).

Comment: Ah OK, got it.  That's why I get UTF8 if I switch the detect order around.

Comment: @Abs Yes, UTF-8 is a strict superset of ASCII. Everything that is ASCII is also valid UTF-8. It's the major reason that it became popular as a Unicode encoding scheme.

Comment: Any Basic (7-bit) ASCII String is valid UTF-8, but the same can't be said for Extended (8-bit) ASCII Strings, which only match for code points `0x00` - `0x7F`

Comment: The reason for that being that UTF-8 uses the highest bit to mark a byte as being part of a multi-byte character.

Answer (score 2):

As @Phylogenesis mentioned in the comments, ASCII characters under 0x7F are valid UTF-8.  Unless you have a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in your data, the text is both valid ASCII and UTF-8.  You've specified that ASCII is an option before UTF-8, so it is returned.

For example: https://ideone.com/DupS4A

```
<?php

$str = "apple";
// Returns ASCII
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($str, "ASCII, UTF-8"));

// 0xEFBBBF is the byte order mark in UTF-8
$str_with_bom = chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) . "apple";
// Returns UTF-8
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($str_with_bom, "ASCII, UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, this makes sense.