# php mb_convert_encoding function doesn't work from ASCII to latin-1

Tags: php, encoding

```
        //reencoding string from UTF-8 to Latin1
        echo mb_detect_encoding($out);
        $out = mb_convert_encoding($out, mb_detect_encoding($out),"ISO-8859-1");
        echo mb_detect_encoding($out);
        die;
```

The result printed on my page is :

ASCIIASCII

I already checked the possible encoding supported (http://php.net/manual/fr/mbstring.supported-encodings.php) Latin-1 is knew as ISO-8859-1. But nothing changes...

---[EDIT]---

this is what I get when I print $out before the mb_detect_encoding();
My string is correct. Maybe it could be a php.ini configuration wich mess it up? I am not able to change it ...

EDI_DC40 0000000000027262 2 SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT201 SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT2 330SOL 96A ORDERSTDX4 LS SERVEURDPL SAPP48 LS SERVEURDPL 1 E2SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT2 X E2BPSDHD1000 00000000000272621 YPR 4803 330 0230 20151002 20151002Z300 7134012207 71 20151002 20151002 E2BPSDITM000 00000000000272622 1 L7820100 9 E2BPSDITM000 00000000000272623 2 L7820400 6 E2BPSDITM000 00000000000272624 3 L9188000 5 E2BPPARNR000 00000000000272625 AG0000510001 E2BPPARNR000 00000000000272626 WE0000510001 E2BPPARNR000 00000000000272627 LQ0000030590 E2BPPARNR000 00000000000272628 ZQ0000990238 E2BPSCHDL000 00000000000272629 1 9 E2BPSCHDL000 000000000002726210 2 6 E2BPSCHDL000 000000000002726211 3 5 E2BPSDTEXT000 000000000002726212 FR E2BPPAREX000 000000000002726213 BAPE_VBAK LX2 E2BPPAREX000 000000000002726214 BAPE_VBAKX X

ASCII
ASCII

[EDIT2]

I still have some issues to get my file encoded in ISO-8851-1.
I juste added `$out = utf8_decode($out);` before to generate my file :

```
    $strFileWrite    =  fopen($filePath, "w");
    $strWritableFile =  fwrite($strFileWrite, $out);
    fclose($strFileWrite);
```

When I add "Ô" at the end of the $out variable, the file is recognized in latin-1, and the ô is well printed. When I add it in the middle of my file, the document is recognized in utf8 and the character "ô" is poorly printed ( � )

Comment: Can you please post what `$out` string contains?

Comment: Also try to use strict mode: `mb_detect_encoding($out, mb_detect_order(), true);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32891278/476):

> Strings have no actual associated encoding, they're merely byte
>   arrays. `mb_detect_encoding` doesn't tell you what encoding the string
>   has, it merely tries to ***detect*** it. That means it takes a few
>   guesses (your second argument) and tells you the first that is valid.

If your original string is ASCII, it's already also valid Latin-1, UTF-8 and a whole bunch of other encodings for that matter, which are all supersets of ASCII. Converting it won't actually change anything. `mb_detect_encoding` preferably detects it as ASCII, since it's the first valid match, and it's as valid an answer as virtually anything else.

If you require Latin-1 and you want to ***confirm*** that your string is valid in the Latin-1 encoding, use [`mb_check_encoding($str, 'ISO-8859-1')`](http://php.net/mb_check_encoding).

Maybe start reading here to understand more: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: Ok I understand the thing. But I need to make a file encoded in latin1. So my question was not "why mb_encode doesn't work" but "how to chose the encoding when saving a file in php" ?

Comment: Nope, you did not understand. Your file is already Latin-1! Merely your way to confirm that is not working as expected, because you're trying to ***detect*** an encoding, which by definition is impossible with any amount of accuracy. Again, you can *check whether your file is valid Latin-1*, you cannot *detect* the encoding and expect it to always match your expectation.

Comment: OK !! Now I thinx I get it. So there was no question at all, work is already done. Thanx a lot, I'll read the doc you sent me.

Comment: I understand better the encoding isues now but I still have a problem. Even if my file is already in latin1, I need it to be recognize as a latin-1 file because the file as to be imported by an other program. I do a  utf8_decode($out); to my string before to apply a fwrite. But it is recognized as a litin-1 file only if it contains special characters ... Any ideas ?

Comment: Again: "detecting" encodings is not a thing. At least not a reliable thing. Plain text files don't "declare" anywhere what encoding they're in. It's up to each individual application to know or figure out the encoding by itself. **There's nothing you can do to make some program recognise your file as a certain encoding.** All you can do is output a file which is correctly encoded, then handle the importing/opening on the other end independently. And again, having said all this, if your file only contains ASCII characters, it's pretty much irrelevant what encoding it's recognised as.

Comment: Apparently, the problem is when I output characters like "ô" ... I use utf8_decode. I should be ok for their import

Comment: Anyway thanx a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2):

At first please note that PHP strings do not have any special 'charset' property. Encoding detection is totally based on string's byte-by-byte analysis.

Your string contain only characters from ASCII scheme, therefore whatever encoding you choose it is always ASCII-compatible (and then detected as ASCII because of higher ASCII priority).

`mb_detect_encoding` compares string bytes against each encoding specified as second argument (which defaults to `mb_detect_encoding`) and returns first encoding that contains all bytes / characters found in string.

Few examples (I've shortened your string for readability):

```
$order = mb_detect_order();
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding('EDI_DC40 0000000000027262', $order, true);

var_dump($order);
// array(2) { [0]=>string(5) "ASCII", [1]=> string(5) "UTF-8" }
var_dump($encoding);
// string(5) "ASCII"
```

Now let's revert the order.

```
$order = [0 => 'UTF-8', 1 => 'ASCII'];
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding('EDI_DC40 0000000000027262', $order, true);

var_dump($order);
// array(2) { [0]=>string(5) "UTF-8", [1]=> string(5) "ASCII" }
var_dump($encoding);
// string(5) "UTF-8"
```

And now let's try to put some non-ascii character into your string. In this situation mb_detect_encoding will realize that this is not ASCII string and will check it against UTF-8.

```
$order = mb_detect_order();
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding('źEDI_DC40 0000000000027262', $order, true);

var_dump($order);
// array(2) { [0]=>string(5) "ASCII", [1]=> string(5) "UTF-8" }
var_dump($encoding);
// string(5) "UTF-8"
```

Because your string contains only ASCII-compatible characters you can safely display, save and edit it as ASCII, event if it comes from UTF-8 source.

Comment: Thanx for the explainations, very usefull. I think I need to read about encoding ...